# heatmap in R how to resize columns labels?

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a data.matrix that is approximately 4000 rows and 100 columns. I am doing a heatmap of the data like:

```
data<-heatmap(data_matrix,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,col=cm.colors(256),scale="column",margins=c(5,10))
```

But the problem that I got is that the labels that appear in the column are too grouped, so it is impossible to visualize them correctly. How I can resize the heatmap so I can see the values of the labels of the column? I tried to print it in pdf, but it only appears a black stripe.
Thanks

I am including a figure of the heatmap, the portion that I want to see are the labels that are in the right part, but they are too close together.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rstudio you can easily resize the graphic window, same holds for Rgui. Alternatively, if you save the plot to file you can use a bigger size for your graphics, e.g. bigger `width` and `height` when calling `pdf` or `png`.

Comment: I have tried that, but with no results. Also heatmap does not allow those parameters. Could you put a coding example? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

First of all it's better to put your output directly to a PDF file - you may use other image formats but PDF is the best because it is a vector output and you can zoom as much as you want:

```
pdf("Your-file.pdf", paper="a4", width=8, height=8)
```

Then it's better to use `pheatmap`( = pretty heatmap) package. It makes really better heatmaps with a color key besides your heatmap. Finally although the `pheatmap()` function tries to reduce the label size while you have many rows, but it fails for really large number of rows. So I use the code below for really high - but not too high - number of rows:

```
library(pheatmap)   
library(gplots)
if (nrow(table) > 100) stop("Too many rows for heatmap, who can read?!")
fontsize_row = 10 - nrow(table) / 15
pheatmap(table, col=greenred(256), main="My Heatmap", cluster_cols=F, 
         fontsize_row=fontsize_row, border_color=NA)
```

You may change `fontsize_col` for the column labels. You have many interesting options like `display_numbers` to have the values inside the cells of your heatmap. Just read `?pheatmap`.

This is an example generated by the default parameters of `pheatmap()` command:

[image]

Finally note that too many rows are easy to read on a display, but useless for print.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cexRow = and cexCol =.

You can get more information into ??heatmap.2

```
# Row/Column Labeling
margins = c(5, 5),
ColSideColors,
RowSideColors,
cexRow = 0.2 + 1/log10(nr),
cexCol = 0.2 + 1/log10(nc),
labRow = NULL,
labCol = NULL,
srtRow = NULL,
srtCol = NULL,
adjRow = c(0,NA),
adjCol = c(NA,0),
offsetRow = 0.5,
offsetCol = 0.5,
colRow = NULL,
colCol = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **pheatmap** (`https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/COMPASS/versions/1.10.2/topics/pheatmap`) you can spread out those labels by adjusting the `cellheight` parameter.

If you are doing this in R notebook, even though the entire heat map will not display in your output window when you run the code, when you save the heat map to your computer using the `filename`  parameter, pheatmap will automatically calculate the optimal size for the output file so that your entire heatmap will be displayed in your output file. If this size is not to your liking you can adjust using `width` and `height` parameters, but it is unlikely you will want to do this.