# How to fit width, lenght, margins and dimensions of a HeatMap/pHeatMap with R

Tags: r, resize, dimensions, pheatmap

This is my very first post and I'm also really new to R (and programming in general).

I've been trying all I've been finding, with posts like this one:

[heatmap in R how to resize columns labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087555/heatmap-in-r-how-to-resize-columns-labels)

But nothing seems to work to me.

The problem here is that the table data that I have to use is kind of big (17 columns and 107 rows) and the labels for the rows are huge..

I need all the columns and rows labels to be clearly seen and distinguished from each other, as well as the rows. Every cell of the heatmap counts.

After running the code that was answered in the previous post for a pheatmap, I get this error (I'm gonna paste all the console says):

```
    > library(pheatmap)   
> library(gplots)
> x <- read.table(file='data1.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, row.names = 1, check.names = FALSE)
> 
> if (nrow(x) > 100) stop("")
Error: 
> fontsize_row = 10 - nrow(x) / 15
> pheatmap(x, col=greenred(256), main='Experiment', cluster_cols=F, 
+          fontsize_row=fontsize_row, wordLengths=c(0,Inf), border_color=NA)
Error in strwidth(t, units = "in", cex = fontsize_row/fontsize) : 
  valor de 'cex' no válido
```

And this is the code I've been using

```
library(pheatmap)   
library(gplots)
x <- read.table(file='data1.tsv', sep = '\t', header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, row.names = 1, check.names = FALSE)

if (nrow(x) > 100) stop("")
fontsize_row = 10 - nrow(x) / 15
pheatmap(x, col=greenred(256), main='Experiment', cluster_cols=F, 
         fontsize_row=fontsize_row, wordLengths=c(0,Inf), border_color=NA)
```

Obviously I downloaded the packages. I also have normal heatmap and heatmap.3 if that would give a better result...

Everything leading to a correct solution will help me a lot !

I attach a picture of the result and the core problem:

· Not all row labels are shown (maybe they should not appear since they
are a lot but...). And, its name gets cut

· Column labels are only 17. They need to be all seen and only few are
shown

[IMAGE.PDF WITH THE BAD RESULT I'M GETTING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yitw4.png)

This is the data1.tsv file that I have to use in case someone wants to try:

https://gofile.io/d/Zqc3ai

I guess the answer is easier than what I imagine but I just don't find it...

Thank you very much !